# Amazon Elastic Search- Install Hunspell Stemmer

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, hunspell

I want to use some dictionary based stemming via the hunspell token filter. I am using Amazon Elastic Search, but not getting how to configure these plugins to my domain. If any other dcitionary stemmer is available in AWS ES then it will be helpful. This service is turning out to be useless.

Comment: Hi, have you figure out this problem? I cant find a solution either

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there is no way to do this. But to get the stemming working, i have used english stemmer, which works well for english words.

I have created a custom analyzer with following settings:

```
"analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "english": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "english_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The question asks for Hunspell stemmer explicitly, not this algorithmic `stemmer` token-filter.